# how to substitute substring with different length in C?

Tags: c, string

Situation as following:
In the first line input a string, then the following lines are 'command'. 2 types of command 'p' and 's', 'p' means printing the string, 's' means substitution.
e.g. Input a string aaabbbcccqwerdd then input sbqwerbkkk
(s means substitution, b acts as a delimiter, therefore it means replacing qwer in the string with kkk)
The expected result should be aaabbbccckkkdd, but instead I got aaabbbccckkkrdd
Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 1023
int main() {
    char str[MAXLEN];
    scanf("%s", str);
    char command[MAXLEN];
    while (scanf("%s", command) != EOF) {
        if (command[0] == 'p') {
            printf("%s\n", str); }
        else if (command[0] == 's') {
            char delimiter[] = {"0"};
            strncpy(delimiter, command+1, 1);
            char *a = command;
            a = strtok(command, delimiter);
            a = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            char *b = command;
            b = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            int alength = strlen(a);
            int blength = strlen(b);
            char *bereplaced = strstr(str, a);
            if (bereplaced == NULL) {
                continue; }
            int aindex = bereplaced - str;
            strncpy(str + aindex, b, blength);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pen and paper is your friend here! Draw the strings on paper, using squares for the separate characters. Use that to figure out indexes or pointers from which you need to copy each part of each string, and how to get the length. Do it for a few different strings, and remember to include both smaller, equal and larger substitutions. Once it starts to work out, figure out the functions needed to get the indexes or pointers and lengths, and start implementing. And don't worry, the code will never look very nice. And put it into a separate function to make it simpler and more maintainable.

Comment: Implementation-wise I would actually recommend *two* "substitute" functions: One to substitute using indexes; And one using delimiters. The delimiter function finds the indexes and uses the first index-based function.

Comment: It is incorrect to do strtok once for one delimiter and other time for other delimiter, as the first call modifies the initial input.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can go wrong here but the main issue is copying from from source string on to itself, there can be memory overlap. Instead declare a new buffer for the result for find/replace operation.

You can define a separate `find_replace` function as follows:

```
char* find_replace(const char* src, const char* find, const char* replace)
{
    if (!src) return NULL;
    char* find_ptr = strstr(src, find); if (!find_ptr) return NULL;
    int find_start = find_ptr - src;
    int find_length = strlen(find);
    char* result = malloc(strlen(src) + strlen(replace) + 1);
    strncpy(result, src, find_start);
    strcpy(result + find_start, replace);
    strcat(result, find_ptr + find_length);
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    char source[] = "aaabbbcccqwerdd";
    char command[] = "sbqwerbkkk";
    if (command[0] != 's') return 0;
    char delimiter[] = { "0" };
    delimiter[0] = command[1];

    char* find = strtok(command, delimiter); if (!find) return 0;
    find = strtok(NULL, delimiter); if (!find) return 0;

    char* replace = strtok(NULL, delimiter); if (!replace) return 0;
    char* result = find_replace(source, find, replace);
    if (!result) return 0;
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. It does the substitution directly into the input string by:

1. Use `memmove` to move the trailing part of the orginal string to its final location
2. Use `strncpy` to copy the substitute substring to its final location

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 1023

int main(void) 
{
    char str[MAXLEN] = "aaabbbcccqwerdd";
    char command[MAXLEN] = "sbqwerbkkk";
    printf("COMMAND      : %s\n", command);
    printf("TEXT BEFORE  : %s\n", str);

    char* pfind = command + 2;                  // skip initial sb
    char* psub = strchr(pfind, 'b');            // find delimiter
    *psub = '\0';                               // terminate replace string
    ++psub;                                     // point to substitute substring
    size_t flen = strlen(pfind);                // calculate length
    size_t slen = strlen(psub);                 // calculate length
    char* p = strstr(str, pfind);               // find location of replace string
    size_t sc = strlen(p);                      // calculate length
    memmove(p + slen, p + flen, sc - flen + 1); // Move trailing part
    strncpy(p, psub, slen);                     // Put in substitute substring
    
    printf("TEXT AFTER   : %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
COMMAND      : sbqwerbkkk
TEXT BEFORE  : aaabbbcccqwerdd
TEXT AFTER   : aaabbbccckkkdd
```

**Disclamer**

In order to keep the code example short, the above code blindly trust that the command and the original string form a legal substitution and that there are sufficient memory for the result.

In real code, you need to check that. For instance check that `strchr` and `strstr` doesn't return NULL.